# Rename only files in directory and subdirectories by adding timestamps infront of the files

Tags: bash

I am trying to rename by adding timestamp at the front of all the files(folders not included) in the directories and sub-directories with bash script.

From this

```
/home/user/folder/A.log
/home/user/folder/folder1/B.txt
```

to

```
/home/user/folder/2018_5_26_12_10_38_A.log
/home/user/folder/folder1/2018_5_26_12_10_38_B.txt
```

This is the bash script that i tried so far.I want bash that enter subdirectoy. My current bash wont enter sub-dirs

```
cd /home/yolo/filename_test

for i in $(ls -al | grep '^-')  
do

mv -T "$i" "$(date -r "$i" +"%Y %m %d %H %M %S" | sed -e 's/ /_/g') "$i""

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
find . -type f -execdir bash -c ' 
    echo mv {,$(date +'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S_')}"${1##*/}" ' _ {} \;
```

this `find`s only `f`iles and changes the directory path to the path that files found each time `-execdir` and rename the files with prepending today's date to them each file at a time.

with `${1##*/}` we remove the leading `./` from the file; and `{,$(...)}"${1##*/}"` expand to `"${1##*/}" $(...)"${1##*/}"` which passing to the `mv` to rename the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need files only in a recursive way, you can use `find` (recursive by default) with flag `type` set to `f`

Something like this should suffice:

```
cd /home/yolo/filename_test

for f in $(find ./ -type f); do
  mv -T "$f" "${f%/*}/$(date -r "$f" +"%Y %m %d %H %M %S" | sed -e 's/ /_/g') "${f##*/}""
done
```

I didn't touch the `mv` part, replace it with whatever you want.

Personally I would use something like:

```
mv "$f" "${f%/*}/$(date -r "$f" +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")_${f##*/}"
```

Keep in mind that you shouldn't use `ls` to list files in a cycle, because a filename could use every character (including `*`, `\n`, etc.), except for `null`.

Comment: Thanks alot . I got the answer.